# Annotate Django Foreign Key model instance

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-annotate, django-aggregation

Is it possible in Django to annotate a Foreign Key instance?

Suppose I have the following models:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
  pass

class Foo(models.Model):
  base_model = models.ForeignKey('BaseModel', related_name='foos')

class Bar(models.Model):
  base_model = models.ForeignKey('BaseModel', related_name='bars')
```

I want to count the `Bar`s belonging to a `BaseModel` attached to a `Foo`, that is:

```
foos = Foo.objects.all()
for foo in foos:
  foo.base_model.bars_count = foo.base_model.bars.count()
```

Is it possible in a single query? The following code is syntactically wrong:

```
foos = Foo.objects.annotate(
  base_model.bars_count=Count('base_model__bars')
)
```

This one would perform that job in a single query:

```
foos = Foo.objects.annotate(
  base_model_bars_count=Count('base_model__bars')
)
for foo in foos:
  foo.base_model.bars_count = foo.base_model_bars_count
```

Is there a way with a single query without the loop?

Comment: No, or at least not at the time of writing, it has been requested though. The `for` loop however is not that much of a performance bottleneck, I think: the counting is done by the database, you simply "move" the data to the item that was already added. The only thing you should add is `Foo.objects.select_related('base_model').annotate(..)`, and likely the loop runs in microseconds.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way with a single query without the loop?

Not at the time of writing. You could use a `Prefetch` object, but that would result in two queries then.

But likely the `for` loop is not much of a problem: the data is already there, so the loop itself will likely take a few microseconds.

What you however forgot (likely only in your example) is to `.select_related('base_model')`, so:

```
from django.db.models import Count

foos = Foo.objects.select_related('base_model').annotate(
    base_model_bars_count=Count('base_model__bars')
)
for foo in foos:
    foo.base_model.bars_count = foo.base_model_bars_count
```

I agree that it is not very convenient, but performance-wise, the loop will likely not matter much, given you do this *after* slicing/pagination.

Comment: Yes exactly, convenience is the main issue with the for loop. I need to do the first half of the job (annotating the query) in one place of the view, likely `get_queryset`, or even as a method from `QuerySet`. The second half (reassigning the data with a loop) in another one, likely `get_context_data`.